# XMLHttpRequest status always zero when firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a code which goes like this:

```
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:9080/MyRestService/viewitems";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        doSomeFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function doSomeFunction(response) {

    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].title +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].singer +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

Works fine on IE but does not work in Chrome and Firefox.
Basically what happens is xmlhttp.status returned is always 0 in Firefox and Chrome. In IE, it returns 200, which allows the processing to commence.

EDITED: to add the whole code of the html page

EDITED: I solved the problem. The problem was due to cross domain scripting. 
I added response header access control parameter in my restful service codes to fix the issue.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code that actually sends the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: don't use sync ajax, chrome and firefox are right to not give you a status for such requests.

Comment: jfriend: I added the rest of the code

Comment: dandavis: what should i use instead?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that Firefox and Chrome are caching the site. If the server then detects that nothing has changed, it does not respond with the status code 200 but rather with the status code 304 "Not modified". The response itself would then be loaded from the cache.

Comment: so to fix this issue, i can just tinker with the firefox and chrome settings?